# Is it possible to attain something like indexed transparency using three.js?

Tags: three.js, transparency

I am struggling with the common transparency sorting issue. I know there are ways around it (like manually sorting the objects or order-independent transparency) but all that can become quite fiddly. I'd be ok if there was a way to have objects that are partly opaque and partly 100% transparent and have them intersect correctly.

In theory this should be possible. Opaque pixels would be rendered to color buffer and z buffer in the standard way and transparent pixels are just left out.

What I'm looking for is something like indexed transparency as it was used with gif files, for instance that all pixels of an object that have the color #FF00FF are not rendered.

I just don't know if and how this would be possible using three.js. Also, I want to be able to use it with custom shaders.

EDIT: Thanks for your comments so far and sorry for the confusion. This is more of a conceptional thing than a specific problem with my code. It's just that I am often faced with the issue that parts of transparent objects cut out parts of other transparent objects which should be in front of them. Also, transparent objects do not intersect correctly, it's always that one covers another. I understand why this happens and that it is a problem which is inherent to the way transparency is treated. But often I only need parts of an object completely transparent, no partial-shine-through-alpha transparency. Which could be possible if there was a way to leave out certain pixels of objects and render the rest like a normal opaque object.

Let's assume I want to have a metal chain and each segment is a PlaneGeometry thing with a texture that shows the shape of an O (and the rest transparent). Now the chain should be shown with correct interlinkage so to say.

Any help welcome!

Cheers!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: ShaderMaterial: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shader#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial . To use this effectively, look at ShaderLib and ShaderChunk in the code. Three.js uses these to build its internal shaders, and the pattern can be used to extend/enhance those, or to create your own. If you want even more flexibility, look into RawShaderMaterial https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shader#Reference/Materials/RawShaderMaterial .

Comment: @Mircode For your metal chain example, all you need to do is set `material.alphaTest = 0.5` and your interlinkages should render correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Looks exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering a three.js scene, and your texture maps contain no partially-transparent pixels -- that is, each pixel is either 100% opaque or 100% transparent, then you can achieve a proper rendering by setting

```
material.alphaTest = 0.5;
//material.transparent = true; // likely not needed
```

The same holds true if you are using a binary alpha-map.

If you are writing a custom shader, then you can achieve the same effect by using a pattern like the following in your fragment shader:

```
if ( texelColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;
```

three.js r.84